# Linqpad DB connections - get it to NOT connect when I open a file?

Tags: linqpad

I have many LinqPad scripts I use to query databases.  These files are all in dropbox so I have all my queries available across computers.  Very handy.

However each script is tied to a database connection, and that connection is not valid across computers.  I'm guessing it has to do with how the passwords are stored. And that's OK.

But what is annoying is when I open a script, LinqPad attempts to connect to the invalid database.  It is frozen while this happens.  Once it is done, all I have to do is change it to the new db and it's fine.   But this freeze interrupts my flow.

Is there a way to tell Linqpad to NOT try to connect when I open a file?

Comment: There are three questions here: one is how to make queries with connections that include passwords to work across multiple computers, the second is whether the LINQPad UI is supposed to freeze when establishing a connection, and the third is how to stop LINQPad from connecting automatically when a query opens. If you are happy to post the first question separately, I'm happy to answer it, as this is potentially very useful to other people. The second question is really a bug report - contact me privately or via the forum and I'll try and help. The third question, the answer is no.

Comment: Joe - you are a hero of .NET ! Yes I will post the first part separately, which will help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890969/how-to-get-linqpad-db-connections-to-work-across-multiple-computers

Answer (score 0):

you can use a connection by connection string
so you can add some read key or any machanics to execute connection

```
using(TypedDataContext context = new TypedDataContext(Connection.ConnectionString)){
        
        context.table.Where(w=>w.ID == 123);
        
    }
```