# How to get LinqPad DB connections to work across multiple computers?

Tags: linqpad

I have many LinqPad scripts I use to query databases. These files are all in dropbox so I have all my queries available across computers. Very handy.

However each script is tied to a database connection, and that connection does not work on different computers. I'm guessing it has to do with how the passwords are stored. Is there a way to get the db connections in the linqpad scripts to be valid across different computers?

Answer (score 0):

After opening the query on another computer, right-click the connection that automatically appears in the Schema Explorer, update the password, and click 'Remember this connection'.

This saves the connection details to your local computer, which takes precedence over the connection details stored in your query.